# AJAX PHP showResponse Multiple DIVs

Tags: php, ajax, html

I have written a currency conversion PHP script which works perfectly.
Even adding AJAX to it is fine.

My problem is that the there are multiple prices on the page that can be converted at any point simply by selecting a different code from a `select` box. This means that only the div for the first form gets updated.

Is this even possible?

Here is my AJAX code

```
function sendRequest() {
    new Ajax.Request("scripts/doconvert.php", 
    { 
    method: 'post', 
    postBody: 'amount='+ $F('amount')+'&convertTo='+$F('convertTo'),
    onComplete: showResponse
    });
}

function showResponse(req){
    $('show').innerHTML= req.responseText;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. jQuery could make it much easier than using native DOM methods, but native DOM methods would work. But basically you can name all the items you want to submit with a class name. When passing the values back to the client, pass the new values in the same order. Loop over the collection of inputs or divs, or whatever they are and set their new values.

When some action occurs, changing a drop down list, you can find the values in the dom you want to update by using document.getElementByTagName and then maybe looking for a class on those elements. You can put those items in an array. You can grab the values from all those items in the order you have them in the array, and send them to the server.

Convert the values and send them back. You can then either grab the array of elements again (with closure), or just select them again the same way you did before. If you send back to the client the new values in the same order, you can then update each element by looping over your array.

Make sense?